# Where can I find the 'Index of /' page of Apache 2 on Debian?

Tags: debian, apache2

Is it a pre-designed page or generated? Note, I am talking about the page you see when a directory is listed, not the default Apache page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When no valid `DirectoryIndex` file is found, Apache will generate the "Index of /" page dynamically. You can [customise it to an extent with `mod_autoindex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html), but it's not particularly straightforward.

For basic customisation, take a look at Perishable Presses [Better Default Directory Views with HTAccess](https://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/). From the article:

> While there are many scripts available to customize the appearance and functionality of default directory navigation, most of these methods are either too complicated, too invasive, or otherwise insufficient for expedient directory styling. In this comprehensive tutorial, you will learn how to use the built-in functionality of Apache's `mod_autoindex` module to style and enhance your default directory views with a smorgasbord of stylistic and functional improvements.

The article is about 13 years old, but the methods outlined continue to work with modern versions of Apache.